# User Input Java to a list and comprehension

Tags: java, user-input

How do I prompt user to input numbers? I want to calculate percentage, so I want user to keep inputing integer. if the user press enter without entering anything then thats where the calculation starts

this is the example output

```
Input Integer:

2
17
1
3

The numbers and percentage:
   2      8.7%
  17     73.9%
   1      4.3%
   3     13.0%
  23    100.0%
```

After the user finish inputting the numbers, I want to sum them and calculate the proportion of each number compared to the sum.

This is what I have done

```
package basic.functions;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Percent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");

        do {
            try {
                int n = reader.nextInt();
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(n));
            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again");
            }
        }

        //When user press enter empty
        while (reader.hasNextInt());
        reader.close();

        //SUM all the integer elements in the list
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : list)
            sum += x;

        //calculate the percentage of each integer that was entered as proportion of the sum
        //for all elements in the list, divide by the SUM then time 100 to get the percentage


        System.out.println("The numbers and percentage:");

        if (sum == 0) {
            System.out.println("Division by 0 not possible");
        }
        else {

            for (int x : list) {

                System.out.println(x + "               " + ((x * 100 / sum) + "%"));
            }

            System.out.println(sum + "               " + ((sum * 100) / sum) + "%");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulation, you have ask 1 integer to the user. Now you just need to ask it again, using a loop and to find a way to exit the loop using a specific condition or input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `reader.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` to your `Scanner` object as suggested in the other answer too.

In addition note that you have to close the `Scanner` using `reader.close();`

You also need `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` to store the integers for later processing.

Lastly,  `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");` is to round the output to one decimal place.

**Edit:**

Now that you need to catch incorrect inputs too, you no longer need `reader.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` so I have removed this line.

Basically, you need to read the `input` as a `String` and then check to see if the user pressed enter (giving an `isEmpty()` `String`) or entered invalid input (caught by `NumberFormatException`).

Here is the code that does this:

```
package basic.functions;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Percent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");

        while(reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String input = reader.nextLine();

            if(input.isEmpty())
            {
                //When user press enter empty
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {        
                    list.add(Integer.valueOf(input));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException exception)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again");
                }
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        //SUM all the integer elements in the list
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : list)
            sum += x;
        //calculate the percentage of each integer that was entered as proportion of the sum
        //for all elements in the list, divide by the SUM then time 100 to get the percentage
        System.out.println("The numbers and percentage:");
        if (sum == 0) {
            System.out.println("Division by 0 not possible");
        }
        else {
            for (int x : list) {
                System.out.println(x + "               " + ((x * 100 / sum) + "%"));
            }
            System.out.println(sum + "               " + ((sum * 100) / sum) + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh, this reader.hasNextInt() because its empty with "( )" that means to close the reader and stop the scanner loop right?

Comment: @Kutam It checks if the next item in the stream is an `int` and keeps the loop running. As soon as it fails to find an `int` it returns `false` and the loop breaks.

Comment: yes thats what i mean. oh and another thing, I was just trying to compile up to the SUM method. why does it return an error as such "incompatible types, unexpected return value"

Comment: You cannot `return` a value from a `void` function. As you can see that your function `main` is declared as `void`. Besides you don't need to return anyway because you just need to display the value. See my code.

Comment: yes I get it now. can you explain to me what is the delimiter and line.separator? why is is needed?

Comment: @Kutam The delimitor is a character which tells the `Scanner` to stop scanning for inputs. By setting it to `line.separator` we tell the scanner to stop as soon as the user presses enter without entering anything i.e. `\n`.

Comment: ohh yes i get it. I introduce an exception handling so that it only accepts integer. how come it only works for the first input? say if the first i enter 1.0 then it will raise the error. but if i put say 10, 1.0 it will produce 10, 10? and if i do more than 2 input, like 10, 20, 1,0 the one counted is only the 10 and 20. Ive updated the code if you want to check

Comment: @Kutam What you want can be done by the reading the input as a `String` using the `reader.hasNextLine()` and `String input = reader.nextLine();` functions of `Scanner` class. I have updated the code in my answer. So see my edit and report if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have methods for the statistic part:

you need a scanner, a list of integers, and set the [delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) of the scanner to  a platform independent **[line.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)**

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
myScanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println("give some int...");
while (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
       list.add(myScanner.nextInt());
}

myScanner.close();
System.out.println("now calculating");
doMath(list);
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Nice idea, I don't use the Scanner enough but I never thought about that kind of loop ! I will remember it without a doubt

Comment: the first one worked, but now im stuck with how to do the comprehension on the list. I tried iterating through it but there are lots of error. Ive updated the code, can you check please

Comment: I see:) you need to work with the list after you exit the while loop